# Gradle downloads to ?/.gradle directory when running tasks

Tags: gradle

Gradle created a `?/.gradle/` in the directory that gradle was run in. We would expect the cache directory to be created at `~/.gradle`.

Example:

```
/project           # Project root and cwd when running gradle command
    /.gradle       # Expected - project-specific gradle folder
    /?             # Directory literally named with a question mark
        /.gradle   # Unexpected - Global gradle folder with wrappers and cached artifacts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user running the scripts did not have a home directory, giving the user a home directory or specifying a gradle-user-home solved the issue:

```
gradle --gradle-user-home=/foo/bar ...
```

or

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME=/foo/bar gradle ...
```

Comment: or set env property `GRADLE_USER_HOME`

Answer (score 2):

let's find it out why it behaves like this.
As gradle use following code to get user home:

`System.getProperty("user.home");`

Follow the [link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c#l576) for openjdk 8 source code.
It comes to conclusion: When JVM can not found user name in os, it will use *?* as a return. So gradle will create *?/.gradle* for usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different folders gradle stores information. `~/.gradle` is used to store downloaded artifacts, gradle wrappers, etc. Basically everything that can be shared between multiple builds. The `.gradle` folder in your project is used to store project specific information used for example by the gradle up-to-date check mechanism.

Comment: I updated the question with the directory structure we were seeing after running a gradle command. We saw both `.gradle` and `?/.gradle` in the project directory.

Comment: the "/?" folder is nothing that gradle creates by default. seems this is done somewhere in your build logic.